# How can I keep my backlight from turning off on my Lenovo G50-30 laptop?

Tags: backlight

How would I keep the screen backlight from going out after a very short time? My laptop is the Lenovo G50-30 and this is causing me issues with this happening all the time. Could you please assist me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to change the setting from within [system settings > brightness and locking]. (Actual inscriptions may differ as I use the German version and just translated those I see to English)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu 14.XX:

- Open system settings
- Type in Brightness in the top right search box and choose "Brightness and Lock"
- From here you can choose the settings for adjusting how long until the screen turns off and when it automatically locks.

If you're using Kubuntu 14.XX
 - Open system settings
 - Navigate to "Display and Monitor"
 - On the left panel, you'll see three icons, click on "Screen Locker"
 - Adjust these settings to what you desire
 - You might also need to go to "Power Management" (also in system settings towards the bottom) and edit those settings as well. I believe these settings are responsible for the dimming and going out after a short period of time.